# ZipFile.write() throwing a CRC error

Tags: python, zip

I want to add a file to an already created zip file using python.

Below is the code :

```
try:
        conn='1.properties'
        fileName='/home/pbnagara/temp/Zip1.zip'
        myZip = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, mode='a')
        myZip.write(conn)
        myZip.close()
except Exception:
        print 'Exception occurred while writing to Zip file: ' + fileName
```

When i try to unzip it, the archive is corrupted and it throws the below error:

> extracting: 1.properties    bad CRC afe265f4  (should be f998eec6)

Can you please let me know what's going wrong here?

Will having a different suffix[other than .zip for the archive name] cause any error ?

Comment: Does this happen when you try to unzip it outside python? Surely if you run that code it should print what's beneath the `Exception` as you're catching _everything_ including `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: What are you using to extract the archive ? I tested it on my side and I had no problems extracting the archive with 7-zip.

Comment: Getting the error with 7-zip and also with unix "unzip"

Comment: @user170008 you receive no errors when you try to unzip the original .zip file? (from within or outside of Python)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely the file you're opening in append mode is corrupted or isn't a valid zip-file, or uses some zip-extensions not supported by ZipFile class.